# update phone numbers in different server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a phone_field in tableB on serverB with incorrect phone # and phone_field in tableA on server with the correct phone # for the same person_ids. Is there a way to update tableB with TableA phone#. Both the tables are identical and have same number of fields.I use sql server 2008. any help appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Is it just one record?

Comment: no, there are more than 100k records, out of which some 10k records have Phone# that does not match the tableA phone #

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one is a linked server to the other, you need to add the server names:

```
UPDATE tb 
SET    tb.Phone_field = ta.Phone_field 
FROM   ServerB.dbName.SchemaName.TableB tb 
   INNER JOIN ServerA.dbName.SchemaName.TableA ta 
           ON tb.Person_id = ta.Person_id
```